Omnet timestamp different from server timestamp in MoSTScenario
i have a problem while using veins (v5.2) with the veinsInet plugin, omnetpp(v6.0.1) and sumo (v1.8).
I am trying to run the MoSTScenario (https://github.com/lcodeca/MoSTScenario). After a few seconds of this scenario i got the error:
ASSERT: Condition 'omnetTimestep == serverTimestep' does not hold in function 'processSimSubscription' at veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIScenarioManager.cc:953 
The *.manager.updateInterval in the omnet.ini and the step-length from the sumocfg are set to the same value..
Part of sumocfg:
    <time>
        <begin value="14400"/>
        <step-length value="0.1"/>
        <end value="50400"/>
    </time>

Part of omnet.ini:
*.manager.updateInterval = 0.1s
*.manager.firstStepAt = 15000s
*.manager.connectAt = 14400s

With the current settings the simulation runs until simTime > 16000 but < 17000.
When i change the firstStepAt to a value > 17000 i will get the error directly..
With bigger step-length the error also appears but later..
The time difference is very small.. One debugging example:
Servertime: 17000099999999998
Omnettime: 17000100000000000
Why are the clocks asynchrony? All of my other scenarios are working..
Thanks for your help!
